# Why my new GTX 660m's clock drops drastically after running few seconds

Tags: hardware-failure, gpu

I bought a Lenovo Y580 laptop few days ago, this model is equipped with GTX 660m graphics card.

However, the game performance is unbelievably poor since it out from the box. I realized there is something wrong with this graphics card.

I downloaded GPU-z, and did a simple test. And I was shocked by the fact that my GTX 660m graphics card is running at 135.0mhz core clock. (It should be 835mhz at least!) Even the integrated graphics card "Intel HD graphics 4000" can run at 650mhz.

Further examining showed that in the *first few seconds* GTX 660m was actually running at 835mhz, however the core temperature quickly reached 90+°C and the clock (maybe) automatically drop to 135.0mhz.

[image]

This is very strange. Anyone has any idea what's going on here?

Comment: At 0% load, it should be running at minimum speed. We need to see what it looks like under load.

Comment: @trVoldemort - Why are you blocking out critical information in your screenshot?  As David points out.  The GPU isn't under load so it won't be running at full speed.  If at full speed it is overheating the computer, clearly, there is a problem with the fans, invest in a cooling pad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply it's massively overheating and dropping its clock speed to avoid damaging itself and the laptop. Likely the fan is either gunked up, or not connected properly.

If it's new, return it and get it fixed/replaced.

Comment: I don't think we have sufficient evidence to reach that conclusion.